composite derivative and variable change
I'm asking for help with this calculation that I've been racking my brain over for two days!
We have a variable change:
$$p=e^{-\gamma t}\hat p$$
$$dp = d \hat p e^{-\gamma t}$$
Now the pdf becomes
$$\hat \rho (\hat p,t)d \hat p = \rho (p,t) dp = \rho(e^{-\gamma t}\hat p, t) e^{-\gamma t} d \hat p $$
So
$$\hat \rho (\hat p,t)= \rho(e^{-\gamma t}\hat p, t) e^{-\gamma t}$$
Now, my problem! We have to make the calculation $\frac{\partial{\hat \rho}}{\partial{t}}$
I can't get the right result which is
$$\frac{\partial{\hat \rho}}{\partial{t}} = (\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} - \frac{\partial{ \rho}}{\partial{p}} \hat p \gamma e^{- \gamma t} ) e^{- 3 \gamma t} - 3 \gamma \rho e^{- 3 \gamma t}$$
From my calculation I have instead something like
$$\frac{\partial{\hat \rho}}{\partial{t}} = (- \gamma e^{- \gamma t} \hat p) (\rho \frac{\partial{[e^{- \gamma t}]}}{\partial{p}} + e^{- \gamma t} \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}}) + e^{- \gamma t} \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} - \gamma \rho e^{- \gamma t}$$
which is wrong!
Could you show me the calculations in detail. A thousand thanks!
However, the calculations continue like this:
$$\frac{\partial{\hat \rho}}{\partial{t}} = (\frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{t}} - \frac{\partial{ \rho}}{\partial{p}} \hat p \gamma e^{- \gamma t} ) e^{- 3 \gamma t} - 3 \gamma \rho e^{- 3 \gamma t} = \gamma p \frac{\partial{\rho}}{\partial{p}} + 3 \gamma \rho + m \gamma T \frac{\partial^2{\rho}}{\partial{p^2}} \hat p \gamma e^{- \gamma t}e^{- 3 \gamma t} - 3 \gamma \rho e^{- 3 \gamma t}$$
$$ = m \gamma T e^{- 3 \gamma t} \frac{\partial^2{\rho}}{\partial{p^2}} = m \gamma T  e^{- 2 \gamma t} \frac{\partial^2{\hat \rho}}{\partial{\hat p^2}}$$
But for now I would like to understand the initial part

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please make sure you are clear on whether you are deriving with respect to the arguments of the functions, or with respect to independent variables (and which are the independent variables when $p$ is a function of $\hat p$ and $t$).
